# Calling app.quit() in electron app does nothing in Windows (but works on Linux)

Tags: electron

I have an electron app that runs mostly in the background, occasionally opening a window in the bottom-right corner of the screen in response to messages received by a NATS client.

The app has a tray icon and menu with a quit button that calls `electron.app.quit()`

```js
const createTray = () => {
  const trayIconPath = path.join(__dirname, "icon.png");
  tray = new Tray(trayIconPath);
  const menuTemplate = [
    {
      label: `Version: ${app.getVersion()}`,
      type: "normal",
      enabled: false
    },
    ...(other buttons here)...
    {
      label: "Quit",
      type: "normal",
      click: app.quit
    },
    { label: "Exit", type: "normal", click: app.exit }
  ];

  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
  tray.setToolTip("Tooltip text");
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
};
```

On linux, this button works fine. The app quits, and when I check `ps`, I find that the task is no longer running.

On windows, it doesn't seem to do anything. The app continues running, the icon remains in the tray, and if I click any of the other buttons in the tray, they act normally as if the app were never closed.

Note: the exit button works on both platforms, but doesn't fire the `will-quit` event, which I would like to add a handler to.

To attempt to debug, I've tried adding handlers to the `before-quit`, `will-quit` and `quit` events:

```js
app.on("before-quit", () => {
  console.log("before-quit");
  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
    title: "Before Quit",
    message: "Before Quit",
    buttons: ["OK"]
  });
});

app.on("will-quit", () => {
  console.log("will-quit");
  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
    title: "Will Quit",
    message: "Will Quit",
    buttons: ["OK"]
  });
});

app.on("quit", () => {
  console.log("did quit");
  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
    title: "Did Quit",
    message: "Did Quit",
    buttons: ["OK"]
  });
});
```

On Linux, after pressing Quit, I see all three dialogs open before the app quits.

On Windows, after pressing Quit, I see the `Before Quit` dialog open, but neither of the other two do.

There are no other handlers on these events at the moment.

I have tried adding a try/catch block around the call to app.quit by replacing the click handler of the Quit button with the following method:

```js
const quit = () => {
  try {
    mainWindow.close();
    app.quit();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
      title: "Error quitting",
      message: err.message,
      buttons: ["OK"]
    });
  }
};
```

After making this change, and trying to quit the app on Windows, I still see the `Before Quit` dialog, but do not see any error dialog, and the app continues to run.

So, what is preventing my app from quitting properly in Windows? Is there anything more I can do to debug the issue?

Comment: You can try to force close electron via `process.exit()` or even `process.kill(process.pid)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from electron 6.0.1 to 6.0.10 seems to have resolved this issue